# When irreducibility of a polynomial implies its irreducibility over an extension field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $k \subsetneq K \subsetneq \bar{K}$ be a field extension,
where $\bar{K}$ is an algebraic closure of $K$.
(The fields are of characteristic zero).

If $f \in k[T]$ is an irreducible polynomial over $k$,
when is it irreducible over $\bar{K}$?

(An easy counter-example: $\mathbb{Q} \subsetneq \mathbb{R} \subsetneq \mathbb{C}$, $f(T)=T^2+1$).

Actually, I am interested in the case where $k=\mathbb{C}(X)$, $K=\mathbb{C}((X))$,
so $\bar{K}$ is the Puiseux field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over an algebraically closed field, the only irreducible polynomials are linear polynomials (since every nonconstant polynomial has a root, and hence a linear factor).  So the only irreducible polynomials over $k$ that are still irreducible over $\bar{K}$ are linear polynomials.

Comment: Thank you very much! My question as I wrote it has an easy answer, the one above. But truly I was confused and meant to ask about an irreducible polynomial $f$ over $k(x,y) \subsetneq K(x,y) \subsetneq \bar{K}(x,y)$ (of course, $\bar{K}(x,y)$ is not algebraically closed).

Comment: Ah, yes, that is a more interesting question.  I suggest you post it as a new question.

Comment: Thanks, I will now post it.