# When irreducibility of a polynomial implies its irreducibility over an extension field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Let $k \subsetneq K \subsetneq \bar{K}$ be a field extension,
where $\bar{K}$ is an algebraic closure of $K$.
(The fields are of characteristic zero).
If $f \in k(x,y)[T]$ is an irreducible polynomial over $k(x,y)$,
when is it irreducible over $\bar{K}(x,y)$?
Actually, I am interested in the case where $k=\mathbb{C}(X)$, $K=\mathbb{C}((X))$,
so $\bar{K}$ is the Puiseux field.

When I have asked [that question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980924/when-irreducibility-of-a-polynomial-implies-its-irreducibility-over-an-extension) I actually meant to ask the current question.

Comment: I don't understand the notation for $K$. Shouldn't it be $\mathbb C((X))$?

Comment: Yes you are right, I meant $K=\mathbb{C}((X))$. (I have now corrected my question thanks to your comment).